# Does Dirichlet Density Imply Logarithmic Density over Primes?

Tags: analytic-number-theory

We define the Dirichlet density of a set $P$ of primes to be the limit
$$\lim_{s \longrightarrow 1+} \frac{\sum_{p \leq x, p \in P} p^{-s}}{\log \left( \frac{1}{s-1} \right)}$$
whenever it exists and the logarithmic density of $P$ to be the limit
$$\lim_{x \longrightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{\log \log x}\sum_{p \leq x} \frac{1}{p}$$
again subject to existence of the same. Of course these have corresponding "natural" analogues (as in there do exist notions of Analytic and Logarithmic Density over $\mathbb{N}$ and to the best of my knowledge, Tenenbaum proves that analytic density of a set $A \subset \mathbb{N}$ (over $\mathbb{N}$) exists if and only if the corresponding logarithmic density does, in which case the values of the two are equal).

I was curious about what happens in the above situation. Here ([Dirichlet density](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1054214/dirichlet-density)) it has been proven that the existence of the above logarithmic density implies that of the above Dirichlet Density, and in that case the values of the two are equal. However, I have not been able to find a proof or counterexample for the opposite implication. Any help or suggestions would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Outside of sets (more generally coefficients $\ge 0$ and $O(...)$) it doesn't imply it because $\sum_p p^{-s}+\sum_n n^{-s+it}\log n $ satisfies the same asymptotic as $\sum_p p^{-s}$ near $s=1$ but $\sum_{p\le x} p^{-1}+\sum_{n\le x} n^{-1+it} \log n \sim \log \log x + \frac{x^{it} \log x}{it}$